# What can cause setting incorrect dates after importing from XML-file to MS Project?

Tags: c#, xml, ms-project

I'm working on a program, kind of `MS Project`, using `C#`. There is a function, which generates `XML-file`, which can be imported to MS Project to view project structure in another way.

In 95% cases, it works well, but sometimes, I'm getting wrong dates in MS Project after importing. However, dates in the generated file match to those, which I see in my program. So it seems, that the problem is in MS Project.

I know one of the problems: MS Project's calendar is simple (5-2), so it doesn't know about holidays and so one. But tasks, which start and end dates don't contain weekends and holidays can be incorrect, too.

If you need some *.xml examples, I'll give them to you.

Comment: Are the string dates from the XML being converted to a DataTime object properly?  Usually date issue are due to the string not properly being converted correctly.  The MS project uses the same driver as Excel or Access (either JET or ACE).  Both of these drivers attempt to guess at the DateTime format if one is not specified.  It is basically the same issue if you set an excel cell to GENERAL format that dates get converted to numbers and number get converted to dates due to the guessing.

Comment: @jdweng, the program generates dates like this:  <Start>2019-12-16T00:00:00</Start> <Finish>2019-12-18T00:00:00</Finish> so, that in MS Project this date is 17.12-19.12. Is it right format?

Comment: How is the c# parsing the XML.  Specifically the DateTime.  The c# code should be passing the Project a DateTime object not a string.